# String formatting using a list

Tags: python

I have a list of keywords from which I want to create a certain query named `_KDWS`. I have a query suffix `prefix` and I want to return a string that starts with `prefix` and is followed by every keyword from `_KWDS`:

something like this:

```py
    def _generate_query(self, prefix): # TODO
         return f"{prefix} {kwd for kwd in self._KDWS}"
```

I expect the returned string to look like this:

```py
    "prefix kwd1 kwd2 kwd3 kwd4 kwd5 ... kwdN"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
def _generate_query(self, prefix):
    return f"{prefix} {' '.join(self._KDWS)}"
```

---

So the `f-string` isn't very useful now, and something like that could be nice too

```
def _generate_query(self, prefix):
    return ' '.join([prefix, *self._KDWS])
```